# Autoamtically replace round bracket with curly bracket

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
text = "The equation is Ue^(jα)."
```

I would like to automatically replace the `(` brackets with `{` brackets when there is a `^` in front of the first round bracket.

So I tried:

```
text = "The equation is Ue^(jα). Some brackets like those () should stay. If this symbol ^ is alone nothing should happen. "
text = re.sub(r'^((.*?))<',r'^{\1} ', text)
text
```

...but it does not seem to work. Any idea how I could make it work?

Some brackets like those `()` should stay. If this symbol `^` is alone nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape some chars:

```
>>> text = "The equation is Ue^(jα). Some brackets like those () should stay. If this symbol ^ is alone nothing should happen. "
>>> re.sub(r'\^\((.*?)\)',r'^{\1} ', text)
'The equation is Ue^{jα} . Some brackets like those () should stay. If this symbol ^ is alone nothing should happen. '
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !